# City name without demonym in "Belgrade journal Philosophia"

Tags: word-order, demonyms

The apparent peculiarity of the phrase mentioned in the title is that the city name itself is used at the beginning of the phrase instead of its demonym *Belgradian*. Is there a rule of English grammar regarding this situation?

Here is a sample sentence containing the above-mentioned phrase:

> Review of the first part of Husserl's Krisis as published in the Belgrade journal Philosophia ...

Comment: Google Books has just one written instance of [the Belgradian government](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+Belgradian+government%22) (from 1867), as compared to an estimated 9,780 hits for [the Belgrade government.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+Belgrade+government%22) I'd stick to the latter ("noun adjunct") form for all contexts except *a Belgradian = **an inhabitant of Belgrade**.* You don't get any such choice with most city names anyway (London, Dublin, Cardiff, New York, etc. don't really have "demonymics").

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers. But isn't Londoner the demonym for London?

Comment: That version works for *an inhabitant of London*, but you can't refer to *the Londoner government*. And so far as I know, there isn't even an equivalent form for ***Cardiff***, etc. anyway. You can *always* use the straight noun form adjectivally, and many of the inflected versions *(Belfastian, Brightonian)* sound more than a little "weird" to many. Not to mention that some *(Mancunian, Novocastrian)* aren't all that easy to "decipher" if you haven't met them before. Attributive nouns are a good "one size fits all" approach.

Comment: Attributive nouns (ie nouns used attributively) are extremely common in English. That's not the same though as saying that they can be used carte blanche. But 'place-name + head noun' strings (as in Liverpool Echo, London Eye, Plymouth paper, Africa Cup ...) are very likely to be acceptable when there is no 'reasonable' ('Cuban' rather than 'Liverpudlian') adjective available. Sometimes, even when there is ('African'). In individual cases, you should check online for usage. FF has done this for you here.

Comment: Thanks  @EdwinAshworth ... Sorry, but what does FF mean?

Comment: What I meant was there's there's no "rule of English grammar" telling you whether to use ***Belgrade*** or ***Belgradian*** in your specific context. But a useful "rule of thumb" is that you're unlikely to often be "non-idiomatic" if you stick to straightforward noun adjuncts for all contexts where you haven't often seen an alternative form being used. So it's the ***British** government*, not ***Britain** government* (but I seriously doubt you'll see any such alternative for the ***New Zealand** government*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks. I got the answer ... I was just wondering what EdwinAshworth meant by _word_ "FF" ... now I realized that he was referring to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no demonym for Belgrade listed in any of the major dictionaries.

If you need to invent one, "Belgradian" best fits existing patterns for creating demonyms from proper nouns. Judging by data available from Google Trends, ["Belgradian"](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=2010-01-02%202018-02-02&q=belgradian) shows a meager level of popularity from 2010 to present. It's not much, but it's more than other potential demonym forms have.

Due to the unpopularity of this term, however, it is probably best to avoid it. Try something like this instead:

> [...] the first part of Husserl's Krisis as published in the journal "Philosophia" out of Belgrade.

Comment: Thank you @r-mac. Just to clarify: The sample sentence was not by me, I just copied it from the net.

Comment: I have to say your *out of Belgrade* strikes me as somewhat "slangy" - akin to the modern usage in, for example, *We met the singer Bono out of U2*. I'd just go with *...published in the Belgrade journal "Philosophia".*